# Java: exchanging data between opened jPanel and jFrame

Tags: java, variables, jframe, jpanel

From the already opened jPanel I open the jFrame "FastSearch" search window using the following method:

```
new FastSearch().setVisible(true);
```

which lists the search results. When I select one of the search results I want to send the value back to the parent jPanel which opened the child jFrame "FastSearch".

I thought it would look something like this:

```
ParentWindow.targetVariable = theValueFromTheOpenedForm;
```

But of course, it doesn't work.

How do I pass data between opened jPanel and jFrame?

Thanks in advance

Comment: More detail needs to be given about how you are trying to access the `JFrame` from the `JPanel` (or vice versa?). When are you trying to access `theValueFromTheOpenedForm` and from whom (`JPanel` or `JFrame`)?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to pass the object through to the `FastSearch` class in some way. Either in the constructor or through some other method. I'm assuming there is probably a listener interface.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try something with the constructor.
I'm having problem getting the reference to the method in the opened panel. I can get the reference to the panel container, but not the method itself.

I tried making the method in the panel static, but i know static should not be used lightly.

Comment: If the `FastSearch` class is something you have the source for you can just modify it and either pass the parent through or add a listener interface.

Comment: I've abandoned the whole 'separate windows' concept, now it's all in the same panel, so everything is in one place.

Thanks for advices, I'm sorry I couldn't implement them.